# Python 3 ~ Find position of letter in a grid

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a grid of strings such as: `grid = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']`, 
I am wondering how to find the coordinates of a letter, for example the letter D would have coordinates `[1,0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myletter = 'D'
grid = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']
for index, value in enumerate(grid):
    if myletter in value:
        subindex = value.index(myletter)
        break

print [index, subindex]
```

So what's going on...  If you want to loop through a list and access the index while you're at it, the best way to do this is enumerate.

The easiest way to test if something is in a string or a list is just to test if it is in it.  That is `value in L` returns true if the value is in the list L.  Finally for lists and strings, `L.index(thing)` gives you the index of that thing.

Comment: Thank you, this worked out. I will select it as an answer in 8 minutes when it lets me.